# Display a directory path in a jLabel

Tags: java, swing, file

I'm currently producing a programme for finding files in a singular directory, every file in that directory will be a '.txt' file and will start with an integer going from '0' upwards, '+1' for every file.

I want to be able to find a file and open it dependant on this number, I have the code below but cant seem to be able to figure out how to set the file-path of the result as the text inside of a jLabel. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.s. 'info' is the jlabel's name

```
private void searchbutMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)    {                                       
String search = jTextField1.getText();

switch(butt){
case("name"):
    File f = new File("W:\\Data\\Customers\\");
    File[] matchingfiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.contains(search) && name.endsWith("txt");
}
}); System.out.println(f);info.setText("Click to View customer: "+  f.getAbsolutePath() );
    break;

case("num"):
    File f1 = new File("W:\\Data\\Customers\\");
File[] matchingfiles1 = f1.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.startsWith(search) && name.endsWith("txt");

}
});System.out.println(f1);

info.setText("Click to View customer: "+ f1.getAbsolutePath());
    break;

}
}
```

Comment: `f1.getAbsolutePath()` or `f1.getCanonicalPath()` when you invoke `info.setText()`

Comment: Yes, or it just displays the base path in the new file parameter

Comment: Your fix still only displays the original path to the directory I'm searching in

Comment: Use one of matchingfiles isnt that obvious?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use `matchingfiles` instead of `f1`?